# How to replace all global variables by another variable?

Tags: php, regex, replace, str-replace, regular-language

I'm trying to replace any global variables in my example to a specific value `$var` as shows in the following example:

(example.php)

```
<?php 
// before
$firstname = $_GET['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$age = $_REQUEST['age'];
?>
```

As shown in the example above, I want to change any global variables `$_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST` automatically in the php file to specific value `$var` in the php file.

Here is what I did to get each line and check if the line of code have `$_POST` or `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`, then I'm trying to change any global variables in the file to specific value `$var`.

(test.php)

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("example.php");
$lines = explode("\n", $file);

$var = '$var';
foreach ($lines as $key => &$value) {

if(strpos($value, '$_GET') !== false){
     // Replace $_GET['firstname'] and put $var
}
elseif(strpos($value, '$_POST') !== false){
     // Replace $_POST['lastname'] and put $var
}
elseif(strpos($value, '$_REQUEST') !== false){
     // Replace $_REQUEST['age'] and put $var
}

}
?>
```

The expected results to be after replace any global variables to `$var` is as following:

(example.php)

```
<?php

// The expected results to be after replace all global variables by $var
// This is how I expect the file to looks like after replace

$firstname = $var;
$lastname = $var;
$age = $var;

?>
```

I appreciated if anyone anyone can help me to find a suitable way to replace any `$_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST` exist in the file by `$var`.

- note: I want to replace any `$_GET[], $_POST[], $_REQUEST` by `$var`, $var to be stored as following:

```
<?php
$firstname = $var;  // Just change text (remove $_GET['firstname', and put $var] in php file
$lastname = $var;  // Just change text (remove $_POST['lastname', and put $var] in php file
$age = $var;  // Just change text (remove $_REQUEST['age', and put $var] in php file
?>
```

- Note: This is how I hope the php file to be looks like.

Comment: $_REQUEST is the same as doing either $_GET or $_POST so you can probably just use $_REQUEST instead of the other two.

Comment: my issue is not about `REQUEST` or `POST` or `GET`, I want to replace all global variables in the php file to `$var` ,, see the `example.php` before and after please

Comment: I am aware, that's why I wrote my advice in a comment, and not an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Overton, Kindly if u have an idea how to replace them automatically in the PHP context file

Comment: Just for info, why do you want to do that?

Comment: I want to pass a value later for all global variables in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FdiQgh/1/)

`/\$_(GET|POST|REQUEST)\[[^\]]*\]/'` will match, for example, `$_GET[anything-other-than-a-right-bracket]` and all we have to do is replace it with `$var` and rewrite the file:

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("example.php");
$file = preg_replace('/\$_(GET|POST|REQUEST)\[[^\]]*\]/', '$var', $file);
file_put_contents("example.php", $file);
```

Comment: Warning: file_put_contents() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in

Answer (score 4):

Is that what you want?

```
$file = file_get_contents("example.php");
$lines = explode("\n", $file);

$var = '$var';
foreach ($lines as $key => &$value) {

    if(strpos($value, '$_GET') !== false){
        $value = preg_replace('/\$_GET\[.+?\]/', $var, $value);
    }
    elseif(strpos($value, '$_POST') !== false){
        $value = preg_replace('/\$_POST\[.+?\]/', $var, $value);
    }
    elseif(strpos($value, '$_REQUEST') !== false){
        $value = preg_replace('/\$_REQUEST\[.+?\]/', $var, $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, exactly. But the `example.php` not changed ! @Toto

Comment: @AbdallaWasef: Just write to outputfile all the lines contained in `$lines` array.

Comment: Not me, I still not vote to anyone .. Someone else hehe

Comment: What u mean about writing to output file all line ?

Comment: I tried: `file_put_contents("example.php", implode("\n", $lines));`
 but it is not change anything in the file

Comment: @AbdallaWasef: Works for me, do you have the write access to the outputfile?

Comment: @AbdallaWasef: Don't worry about downvote, I'm sure you didn't. I just ask the anonymous downvoter why they've downvoted.

Comment: Great man, yes it is `file_put_contents(dataset.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied` .. bcz using XAMPP on Mac . will try solve this issue now and update u

Comment: I fixed the permission issue but still not changed, I will try with other laptop, maybe 'Window' to be far from the permission issue.

Comment: Anyway, u solve the main issue, Thanks @Toto. Sure this is the right answer

Comment: What if you had a mixture of say `$_GET` and `$_POST` on the same line?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

The following code will turn `$_REQUEST['thisvar']` into `$thisvar`, as well as any other `$_GET`/`$_POST` variables you have set.

As mentioned in the comments `$_REQUEST` covers both `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value) $$key = $value;
```

**If I modify your example:**

```
$file = file_get_contents("example.php");
$lines = explode("\n", $file);

foreach($lines as $key => $value) $$key = $value;
```

Comment: please can u reflect this code to my example, and show start from `foreach` loop how it will works to replace all global variables to `$var`.

Comment: I add a note in my question to be more clear, I want the `example.php` file to looks like ` $firstname = $var; ` , please have a look for the question